# Convert pure javascript to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to convert pure javascript to jquery, this code is about all lines containing your specified search text will be removed. Here my code:

my code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v306rzhg/4

```
<body>
Search lines for:
    <input type="text" id="addfield0" value="Sometimes|relevance|understand" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px;" />
    <input type="button" style="margin-top:10px;" value="Remove Lines Containing..." onClick="if(document.getElementById('addfield0').value!='') {removelines('containing');}" />
    <input type="button" value="Not Containing..." onClick="if(document.getElementById('addfield0').value!='') {removelines('notcontaining');}" />
    <textarea id="input_output" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; height:150px; resize:none;" wrap="off">Sometimes to understand a word's
    meaning you need more than a definition.
    At Your Dictionary we try to give you all of the tools
    you need to really understand what the word means.
    Seeing the word in a sentence can
    provide more context and relevance.</textarea>
    <textarea id="removed_box" rows="4" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; height:150px; resize:none;" wrap="off"></textarea>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: _"Convert pure javascript to jquery"_... jQuery **is** pure JavaScript. It's just a set of handy pure JavaScript functions. Writing your code with jQuery functions might save you some bytes on file size, but will also make it less efficient (You go through overpowered functions when simple code is doing the job).

Comment: its called vanilla JavaScript :)

Comment: Why don't you try some tutorials on jQuery before asking such "How do I learn jQuery"-questions?

Comment: In your JSfiddle, your variables are hard to read, look into camelCase.

Answer (score 2):

in `Jquery`

here's how to call an element;

instead of

```
document.getElementById('addfield0')
```

just use

```
$('#addfield0')
```

example when getting the value:

```
 $('#addfield0').val()
```

*note: make sure you reference your jquery*

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Downlaod jquery here](https://jquery.com/download/)